# How to get Google cloud Composer (Airflow) environment variable value using gcloud CLI sub commnds

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, airflow, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to retrieve the existing environment variable on an Airflow instance

when I do `gcloud composer environments run MY_ENV_NAME --location us-east4 variables` , it fetch the list of variables correctly

Then I want to see the value of one particular variable, so based on
[airflow CLI documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-ref#variables) , I tried

```
gcloud composer environments run MY_ENV_NAME --location us-east4 variables get MY_VAR
```

but it gave

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.run) unrecognized arguments: get
```

I also tried `--get` and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Though ugly, the following syntax worked. It needs the double dash with space in between

`gcloud composer environments run MY_ENV_NAME --location us-east4 variables -- --get MY_VAR`

Answer (score 0):

```
gcloud composer environments run my-environment \
  --location us-central1 variables \
  -- \
  get my_var
```

I found the other answers to have syntax errors. I can confirm the above works.

Answer (score -1):

Try separating the commands with `--`, i.e.

```sh
gcloud composer environments run MY_ENV_NAME \
--location us-east4 \
-- variables get MY_VAR
```

Comment: unrecognized arguments:
  --variables

Comment: Try putting `airflow` ahead of `variables`: `gcloud composer environments run MY_ENV_NAME \
--location us-east4 \
-- airflow variables get MY_VAR`